# Book an event page

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to setup A form where a user would be signing up to an event but while doing that it will collect the data of the user from their database table automatically while also taking information from the events table and inserting it into another table

Comment: There is no question here. Questions take the form of *"how do I do ...?"* You have stated you have a task to complete but you have not explained what part of this task is troubling you. You cannot expect  some stranger from the internet to write a whole application for you for free. Even if Martin seems determined to prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using primarily to achieve this at the moment? Are you using PHP? In case of PHP,

if you have a user id on whichever user that is going to fill out the form, then you can use that user id to fetch the information from whatever table that you need, and retrieve the information of the user. You then put those into PHP variables for later use. The only way to know which user is which, is by using sessions. This session can be their user id, which I will go by in this example, simply because it's simple and easy.

The handling of form data can be done by a classic form tag with post method and a submit button. You tell the form whichever page it is to supposed to post to.
It can also be handled by AJAX.

You then put those posts into PHP variables, or use them directly, but I personally prefer to put them into variables for clarification. It can look a bit messy using the post variables directly into your query, as well as the security risks it involves.

What it could look like is something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Firstly we need our session (this should be set upon logging by using $_SESSION['userId'].
As mentioned before, I am using a user id as our session variable in this example.
*/

/*
Carry over the session. 
Use session_start() before anything else in a file to get the session of a user.
*/
session_start();

//Put session into a php variable

//mysql_ syntax:
$userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userId']);

mysqli_ syntax, with $conn being your database connection variable:
$userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['userId']);

mysqli_ syntax, with $conn being your database connection variable: 
$userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['userId'])
?>
```

Now what is left, is to construct our form and send that data. Since I personally would prefer to handle the data in another file than the file that contains the form, we're going to tell the form to post to another file. This file will contain our form data, as well as our user data. How we will go by getting our user data is by using the session variable, which conveniently happens to be the user id (which is unique to every user). We can post this with everything else in our form by using a hidden input field carrying the user id variable (just as an example).

```
<!-- 
What we do here is make a form that that tells which page it is going to go to
on submit
-->
<form action="/another_page.php" method="POST">
   <!-- Our hidden input field, carrying the user id -->
   <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>" />

   What brand is your current car?:<br />
   <input type="text" name="carBrand" placeholder="Brand of your car" />

   Tell us a little about yourself:
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="summary"></textarea>

   Rate your experience, 1-5:
   <select name="rating">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
   <br /><br />

   <button type="submit" name="submitButton">Submit form!</button>
</form>
```

Now we go to the other file to handle our data, which we will later put into the second table as per your request.

```
<?php
//This is our POST variables from our form:
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$car_brand = $_POST['carBrand'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];

//Now to our SQL, to get there data of our user:

//Put SQL command into a variable
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name_of_user_table WHERE userId='$userId'";

//Put query into a variable with mysql_ syntax:
$result_set = mysql_query($sql);

//Put query into a variable with mysqli_ syntax:
//$conn still being your connection variable
$result_set = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//The rows in your table in mysql_ syntax:
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);

//The rows in your table in mysqli_ syntax:
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result_set);

/*
Now we can start using our data from the database, and store them into variables. 
The variables depends on your fields names in the database.
We basically have the data stored into an array,
where we need to tell the array exactly which index we'd like to use
(in this case which field we'd like to store into a variable).
*/

//Examples:
$variable1 = $row['name_of_field'];
$variable2 = $row['name_of_another_field'];
[...]
?>
```

Now what is left, is to put everything into your second table, using our variables. Hope this helps :)

It is also very important that you use prepared statements before firing your SQL commands into your database, or at least sanitize the inputs to prevent SQL-injections.

Comment: The question is tagged `[oracle-apex]` which seems to make it highly likely the OP is using [Oracle Apex](http://codecademy.com/programs/fa9e60becfa0bf872cc3b3ed246fced9/items/51e5c49fd0d721df2a26110669a96a9f)  and not PHP. And even less likely that they are using MySQL. We appreciate the effort you have put into this answer but in future you should really pay attention to what the questioner asks and direct your energies to solving their actual problem, using their actual platform.

Answer (score 0):

Martin wrote a really comprehensive answer; I'm not saying that it is wrong (how could I? I don't speak PHP); however, as the OP tagged it as *Oracle Application Express* (not *PHP*), it might not be the best fit.

---

Anyway: that looks like a simple task: if signing up to the event is done by pushing a button (why wouldn't it be?), you'd create a process which does the rest of the job. Either write it in the appropriate process property, or create a stored procedure which collects data & inserts it elsewhere and - in the Apex process - call that procedure.